# Switch to what ever path is input nodejs

Tags: node.js

Lets assume you have installed an electron app and you are asked to input the path to your current project. You might do something like: `~/Documents/projectName`.

How do I, in node take that input and check if it exists, specifically if you entered in the path as shown above?

the reason for this is that I want to see if A) the path exists and B) if theres a specific file there (I'll be using `path.join(dirEntered, fileName.extension)`.

Is there a way to do what I want? I see `chdir` but that changes where the working directory is. which I guess would be fine but doing:

`process.chdir('~/Documents')` Shows: `no such file or directory, uv_chdir(…)`

I want to avoid having the user to enter the full absolute path of their project. That seems "bad to me". And uploading their project isn't necessary, Im reading a single file (so theres no need for upload here).

**Any ideas?**

Is it possible to tap into the cli commands and take this input feed it there and get the result? Or is that over kill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea how to solve it. If the path starts with a tilde, it replaces that tilde with the full home directory of the current user. It then uses `fs.stat` to see if the given path actually exists.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const os = require("os");

var path = "~/Documents";
if (path.indexOf("~") === 0) {
    path = os.homedir() + path.substring(1);
}
fs.stat(path, (err, stats) => {
    if (!err) {
        // document or path exists
        if (stats.isFile()) {
            console.log("Path " + path + " is a file");
        } else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            console.log("Path " + path + " is a directory");
        }
    } else {
        // document or path does not exist
    }
});
```